# Subtractively sweep a solid through another in python (or C++)

Tags: c++, python, geometry, cad

I'm trying to put together a simple program that will let me visualize a series of consecutive cuts on a wood panel using a router with a particular cutting head.  I'm trying to find a geometry library that is capable of subtractively modifying 3D shapes or solids by sweeping other 3D solids through them.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to define a rectangular solid (the wood panel) and then define a bit profile shape, and take cuts through the rectangular solid (sometimes on a straight line, sometimes on a circular arc).  Does anyone know of anything that will do this?

Comment: As an alternative, you could check out the Sketchup Ruby API.

Comment: This is actually a hard problem, as far as I can tell.  I've been looking through the documentation and APIs for most of the packages listed below, and haven't yet been able to figure out a way to sweep a 3D solid through another solid as a boolean subtraction operation.  The closest I've found so far is the 2D-to-3D extrusions that some packages support.

Comment: Okay, CGAL (below) looks like it could do this.  OpenSCAD might, but still looking.

Answer (score 2):

[pythonOCC](http://www.pythonocc.org/) is an interesting option too!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [FreeCAD](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Scripting)'s Python level can supply what you're requesting.

Comment: Written on top of pythonOCC, hence based on OpenCascade.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Cascade](http://www.opencascade.org/)

Comment: This one looks most promising so far as far as I can tell.  I've used PythonOCC and FreeCAD both, but still can't tell if OpenCascade can do a 3D sweep, or if it would have to be kludged together from a 2D extrusion.  Still looking.

Comment: Actually, "most promising" might be too strong -- I'd edit that out if I could edit comments after 5 minutes.  CGAL also looks good -- see my CGAL/Minkowski answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going the C++ way, if you have Direct3D/OpenGL experience, you could muck around with [TetGen](http://tetgen.berlios.de) and [GTS](http://gts.sourceforge.net) to put something together.

**WARNING:** Very Long learning curve.

**UPDATE:** I have experimenting with [Carve CSG](http://carve-csg.com/) recently and am happy with the results so far. You could easily subtract the cut from the wood panel to get the results you want.

Comment: Carve-CSG doesn't seem to be available at the moment -- no downloads, licensing page says "please contact", and so on.

Comment: Ah -- much better.  Thanks Agnel.  Okay, skimming through the Carve source code and docs, it looks like the only way to generate the shape of the cut is to extrude a 2D cutting bit profile along a path, and then fix up the vertices with some sort of revolved bit profile, the way I describe in one of the other answers.  Do I have this right, or do you know of a more direct way to do it in Carve?  I don't see anything in there like CGAL's Minkowski sums, for instance, but maybe it's called something else...

Comment: I don't think there is a more direct way. What you are describing seems to be it.

Answer (score 0):

HeeksCAD might do the job for you. http://code.google.com/p/heekscad/

Answer (score 0):

We are using [sgCore](http://www.geometros.com/sgcore/index.htm)

Very powerful and simple library.

Comment: Proprietary, C++/C#, Mac/Windows only.  Does not appear to support sweeping a 3D object; closest appears to be a 2D extrusion along a curve.

Answer (score 0):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) looks like it might be able to do 3D sweeps, using [3D Minkowski Sums](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Minkowski_sum_3/Chapter_main.html).  (See the "Glide" section further down the page.)

The only limitation I can see so far with using Minkowski sums is that, if sweeping an object through a 3D path, you don't seem to be able to rotate the object at the same time.  (I could be wrong about this.)  Rotating while sweeping would be useful, for instance, if you are trying to simulate cutting a path using a router or milling bit on the outside surface of a rotating cylinder, such as for a 4th or 5th axis rotary table on a milling machine.  But the original question was about sweeping 3D objects along 2D paths, simulating cuts on a plane such as a block of wood, so this limitation might be important to me but not to OP.

CGAL is used by [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/).  OpenSCAD has a minkowski() primitive that appears to use the CGAL 3D Minkowski feature.  OpenSCAD *might* be able to provide a quick feasibility test as well as maybe a long-term toolpath visualization solution.  (The last time I looked at this I didn't think so, but that may have been an older version of OpenSCAD.)

CGAL is C++, open source, dual licensed.  So far I've found two python bindings:

- http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/  -- unmaintained
- http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/  -- experimental, incomplete, not sure if it includes 3D Minkowski yet

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly a library, one way of doing this might be to build on top of the 2D-to-3D extrusion ability that most of these libraries do support.   A tentative algorithm for doing this might be:

1. Get bit profile as a 2D shape (you're likely to have this already).
2. Extrude that profile along the line or arc that is the toolpath, creating a 3D solid that is the shape of the cut.
3. At each vertex (say, where a straight path joins a curved one), do a "rotate extrude" or "revolve extrude" of the bit profile to generate the corner radius -- most libraries should support this operation as well.
4. Repeat from 2 until done with all toolpaths.
5. Do a CSG boolean subtraction of (workpiece - set_of_toolpaths).

That algorithm seems like it might be fraught with edge cases, but I haven't been able to think of any so far.   I'm wondering why, if it's this simple, there aren't more packages already doing it.